# Timeout while running remote script using SPE Remoting

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am running the following script using SPE Remoting (trying to find all images on all sitecore sites, but this doesn't matter as it is off subject for this post):

```
Import-Module -Name SPE
$session = New-ScriptSession -Username admin -Password b -ConnectionUri http://sitecorehostname

$script = {Get-ChildItem -Path "master:\" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Extension -match "png" -or $_.Extension -match "jpg" -or $_.Extension -match "bmp"}}

$TheStuff = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock $script 

Write-Host $TheStuff

Stop-ScriptSession -Session $session
```

This gives me a timeout error:

> Exception calling "ExecuteScriptBlock2" with "5" argument(s): "The
>   operation has timed out" At
>   \Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SPE\Invoke-RemoteScript.ps1:257
>   char:13
>   +             $response = $singleConnection.Proxy.ExecuteScriptBlock2($ ...
>   +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

If I run the same script in the Sitecore Powershell SPE, it runs fine and returns 4413 records.

The httpRuntime setting in my Sitecore root Web,config is:

```
<system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="512000" executionTimeout="3600" enableKernelOutputCache="false" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" requestValidationMode="4.0" enableVersionHeader="false" />
</system.web>
```

So that timeout is at 60 minutes. This script times out in 102 seconds.

Is there a way to increase the timeout, or am I invoking an incorrect script?

**Edit:**

Here is how I implemented the code, based on the answer below:

```
Import-Module -Name SPE
$session = New-ScriptSession -Username admin -Password b -ConnectionUri http://sitecorehostname
$jobId = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
        # This may make the code easier to maintain.
        $extensions = @("jpg", "png", "bmp")
        #Get-ChildItem -Path "master:/media library" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq "CoveoFacet"}
        Get-ChildItem -Path "master:\media library" -Recurse | Where-Object { $extensions -contains $_.Extension } | Select-Object -Property Name, Id, TemplateName
} -AsJob
$results = Wait-RemoteScriptSession -Session $session -Id $jobId -Delay 5 -Verbose
Stop-ScriptSession -Session $session

ForEach($result in $results)
{
    Write-Host $result.Name
    Write-Host $result.Id
    Write-Host $result.TemplateName
    Write-Host $newline
}
```

Comment: One thought, you probably want to restrict `Get-ChildItem` to `/sitecore/media library`, as searching `master:\ `, otherwise it will have to enumerate the ENTIRE content tree (including templates, renderings, all of the content, etc.)

Comment: Is it at all possible that there may be image files in the rest of the tree, outside of the media library directory?

Comment: I would be surprised if there was. Generally the media library is where media items would be stored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to make use of the `Wait-RemoteScriptSession` command. A more ideal scenario than increasing the web.config timeout is to simply poll the server for updates. Another idea after discussing could be that the timeout occurs because there is a significant amount of data serialized and returned by the service. The example filters to a few properties using `Select-Object`.

```powershell
Import-Module -Name SPE
$session = New-ScriptSession -Username admin -Password b -ConnectionUri https://remotesitecore
$jobId = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
        # This may make the code easier to maintain.
        $extensions = @("png","jpg","bmp")
        Get-ChildItem -Path "master:\media library" -Recurse | Where-Object { $extensions -contains $_.Extension } | Select-Object -Property Name, ID, TemplateName
} -AsJob
Wait-RemoteScriptSession -Session $session -Id $jobId -Delay 5 -Verbose
Stop-ScriptSession -Session $session
```

Comment: This is the answer, with no changes to the timeout in the root web.config. I am going to edit the Question to show how I implemented the code.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are changing timeout wrong web.config.

Try to change it in web.config located here:

> sitecore modules\PowerShell\Services\web.config

Comment: Where do I add the timeout attribute in this file? Can you put an example of the file's contents in your answer?

Comment: @crackedcornjimmy same place where you did it in Sitecore root Web.config. system.web>httpRuntime

Comment: I tried that and it exploded with massive fireworks.